# check PasswordBox Value WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, passwordbox

I have a password box, but i also have a textblock as hint text within the control template. I'd like this to be removed when the password box has a value. I have tried this below but it doesn't work, how can I do this?

Simplified XAML :

```
<PasswordBox Height="20" Name="pwdBox" PasswordChanged="pwdBox_PasswordChanged" Style="{DynamicResource PasswordBoxStyle1}"/>

<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" .. >
                    <StackPanel ..>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="LabelTextBlock" ...
                            Text="Password Label"  />
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                Focusable="false"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="HintTextBlock"
                                Focusable="False"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Opacity="0"
                                Text="Enter Your Password" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code Behind :

```
private void pwdBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (pwdBox.SecurePassword.Length == 0)
    {
        HintTextBlock.IsVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        HintTextBlock.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

It says that the name 'HintTextBlock does not exist in the current context'

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a compile error, does it not disappear correctly, etc?

Comment: It says that the name 'HintTextBlock does not exist in the current context - sorry i'm new to wpf.

Comment: @Ziggy31 That's probably because it's part of a Template, not part of your defined XAML. Your options are to either search the rendered XAML for the part to find the control, or bind `HintTextBox.Visibility` to `pwdBox.Text` using an `IValueConverter` to do the check for you. I forget the exact syntax, but Google should have lots of samples of either one :)

Comment: If you want to do xaml only, and keep it in the style template, I would hope you could just set a DataTrigger on your TextBlock so if Content of PART_contenthost = {x:Null} setter visibility = Visible for your HintText and just set the HintText collapsed by default. Except I haven't tested the idea, just a thought. Except as usual, Rachel's got a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the text box `HintTextBlock` is part of Template of `PassworkBox` so it can not accessed directly as it is not part of direct control of window. Use the FindName to find the control in template of passwordbox.

```
TextBlock hintTextBlock = pwdBox.Template.FindName("HintTextBlock", pwdBox) as TextBlock;
if (pwdBox.SecurePassword.Length == 0)
    {
        hintTextBlock.Visiblility = Visiblitity.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        hintTextBlock.Visiblility = Visiblility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I now get an error saying 'isvisible cannot be assigned to -- it is read only'

Comment: You should use the Visibility property instead of IsVisible. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work either, similar error.. is it possible to use opacity?